# bootstrap menu not closing when clicking again on menu button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3 and on a small device, the hamburger icon appears as expected.

If I click on the menu icon, the mobile menu appears. So far so good.

The problem is that I need the menu to collapse back when I click again on the hamburger icon, but that doesn't work.

I also had to include some custom js to close it when clicking on a menu entry as well as on the body.

Here's the code I'm using to display the navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             </button>
             <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/logo.png' ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"/>
             </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 1px;">
       <?php
          wp_nav_menu(array(
            'menu' => 'top_menu',
            'header-menu' => ('Header Menu'),
            'depth' => 2,
            'container' => false,
            'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
            'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
          );
       ?>
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <a href="/booking" class="btn btn-transparent uppercase align-element-center nav-bar hidden-xs">Test</a>
       </ul>
    </div>
 </nav>
```

and this is the javascript I had to add in order to make it collapse when clicking on the menu entry and/or on the body, as well as an attempt to make it close again when clicking on the hamburger icon if the menu is expanded:

```
$('.navbar-nav li a').click(function() {
  console.log('clicked');
  $('.navbar-collapse').attr('aria-collapsed', false);
  return $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});

$(document).on('click', function() {
  return $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});

// Not working!
$('.navbar-toggle').click(function() {
  var expandedMenu;
  expandedMenu = $('.navbar-collapse');
  if (expandedMenu.hasClass('in')) {
    console.log(expandedMenu.hasClass('in'));
    expandedMenu.collapse('hide');
    return expandedMenu.removeClass('in');
  }
});
```

Comment: could you please add a link to a working example using http://www.bootply.com/ or similar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure that you are not including bootstrap scripts twice in your code.

Comment: Strangely enough (don't ask me how that even happened) but I was including that twice. Removed one entry and then started to work perfectly. Thanks

Comment: Old answer but still helped in 2021!

Comment: Thanks a lot! that was the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bootstrap's javascript, there is no need to add custom code at all, to get collapse to work. For me the

```
$(document).on('click', function() {
    return $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

works perfectly on jsfiddle - 
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s0p2a952/5/)
.

I'm assuming you have some errors with your include stuff. Is the console throwing any erros?

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens once you include multiple conflicting Bootstrap java script files.
In **Bootstrap 4**  unlike bootstrap 5 you need to include 3 files:

```
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" 
integrity="sha384- 
KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script 
src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" 
integrity="sha384- 
ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script 
src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384- 
JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[Bootstrap 4 doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js)

In **Bootstrap 5** you need to include only one java script bundle file

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
 integrity="sha384- 
 MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" 
 crossorigin="anonymous">
 </script>
```

[Bootstrap 5 doc bundle file](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#bundle)

or include 2 separate file:

```
<script 
 src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" 
 integrity="sha384- 
 IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" 
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script 
src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384- 
cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[Bootstrap 5 doc separate files](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#separate)